# Roll back a transaction in a post_save receiver?

Tags: python, django

I have a model, User, and I need to create another instance of a model, Client, in the database directly after User has been saved.
To do this, I'm using a receiver, like this:·

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def create_oauth_client(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
                Client.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'], name="Customer OAuth Client", client_type=1)
```

This works in normal conditions, but if for some reason the Client instance is not saved, I need the ability to rollback the creation
of the Customer. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: So you have 3 models - Client, User and Customer?

Comment: no. just User and Client, updated to reflect that,sorry

Answer (score 1):

By rolling back the entire transaction. Taken directly from the docs:

```
a.save() # Succeeds, but may be undone by transaction rollback
try:
    b.save() # Could throw exception
except IntegrityError:
    transaction.rollback()
c.save() # Succeeds, but a.save() may have been undone
```

In other words, if b.save() fails, in your case, saving the client, roll back the whole thing, including a.save(), in your case the User save.

Comment: I don't have access to the transaction object in the post_save receiver method

Comment: just import it django.db import transaction, IntegrityError. It's an API into the DB transactions. Just not sure if it counts as 2 transactions, cos you are using a signal. I presume you are using the signal because there are multiple places in the codebase that you create a User?

Comment: No, because I need the client to b e created after the user is saved, so post_save seemed like the most efficient option.

Comment: Why not just put your client creation code straight after the User creation then, in one view. Then the transaction code above will work like a charm. No point using a signal if there aren't multiple creation points of the user in the codebase.

Comment: `from django.db import transaction` for anyone coming late to the party

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the code block which does user.save() inside transaction.atomic() and then it's like your post_save function is also gonna be atomic and if anything goes wrong everything will roll back.